how to measure significance of improvement between two methods during modeling
Hello everyone I have two methods for developing models. I use a set of input features (set1) for training model1 and another set of input features which have (set1 features + extra set2 features). I then develop spearman correlation between predicted and observed values to compare the two models and see that model2 which have more features is giving better correlation.
For example: Gene1 using model1 has correlation around 0.56
Gene1 using model2 has correlation around 0.62
So the improvement by adding more set2 features is around 0.06

Now, I want to understand whether this improvement of around 0.06 is significant or not or whether this improvement is due to random noise/fluctuations
Can anyone please tell me how I can measure the significance of improvement for each gene model and measure whether adding set2 features which leads to improvement is due to adding more informative features and not due to random noise/fluctuations.

Correlation with what? It’s not clear how you’re evaluating these models.

Hello, correlation is between predicted and observed values

Why are you using Spearman correlation for this? Why don't you use something more common, like the likelihood-ratio test?
